# getElement by id and loop through all elements inside in nightwatch

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

```
<div id="productcontainer" class="products-list" style="display: block;">
<a id="prd_Item_0" class="item-list-300x250">links</a>
<a id="prd_Item_1" class="item-list-300x250">links</a>
<a id="prd_Item_1" class="item-list-300x250">links</a>
<a id="prd_Item_1" class="item-list-300x250">links</a></div>

var ele=document.getElementById("productcontainer");
if(ele)
  {
    tags=ele.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
     {
      if(tags[i])
        {
         tags[i].click();
        }
     }
}
```

I want to do like above in nightwatch js, can anyone help me how to do it like above using nightwtch js.

Thanks in advance

Comment: guys anyone help me here

Answer (score 1):

Use the promise returned by element finder `findElements` and then loop through the anchor elements to perform any operations that you want. Try the below code -

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('#productcontainer a')).then(function(tags){
    for (var i = 0; i< tags.length; i++){
        if(tags[i])
            tags[i].click();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: module.exports = {
  'Demo test NightwatchJS.org' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://www.test.com/')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .elements('css selector', '#productcontainer', function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
          console.log(client)
          
        }
      })
      .end()
  }
  
};   , i want something like this on nightwatch, i dnt know know how to implement above ans, it will be great if you help like this

Comment: @Chethu can you try this - `module.exports = { 'Demo test NightwatchJS.org' : function (client) { client .url('test.com/') .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000) .elements('css selector', '#productcontainer a', function (result) { for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) { console.log(client) } }) .end() } };` Just change you locator from `#productcontainer` to `#productcontainer a`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job ..

```
module.exports = {
  'Iterate over elements and click them': function(browser) {

    function iterate(elements) {
      elements.value.forEach(function(el) {
        browser.click(el.ELEMENT, function(r) {
          browser.assert.ok(r.status === 0);
        });
      });
    }

    browser
      .url('..')
      .elements('css selector', 'div#productcontainer a', iterate)
      .end();
  }
};
```